# How to make a global variable pick a different value every time

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner to JavaScript and I'm trying to make a basic text based RPG that works on console. There is a travel button to work travel function and travel function gives you a random event each time you click it.

And now at this point I need to set some global variables to use both in travel and attack functions but if I put, for example var happened, outside the travel function it takes a random event once and then every time I click travel it logs the same event to the console. So how can I make a global variable pick another value whenever I click the travel button?

Edit: My main goal here is to make HP a global variable so I can use it in the attack function I will create, and to do that i need to make happened and enemy global variables too.

```js
function travel() {
  var happened = pickEvent();
  var enemie = pickEnemie(happened);
  console.log("______---------You traveld 3 miles---------______");
  console.log(happened);
  if (happened === "You are under attack:") {
    console.log(enemie);
    var HP = enemieData(enemie, "hp");
    console.log(HP);
    document.getElementById("travel").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("attack").style.display = "inline";
  }
}

function pickEvent() {
  return ["Nothing happend...", "You are under attack:", "Some one should have dopped this:", "You see 
    a structure here: "][Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
  }

  function pickEnemie() {
    return (["Dire Wolf", "Goblin", "Snake", "Skeleton"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]);
  }

  function enemieData(monster, stat) {
    var monsters = {
      "Dire Wolf": {
        "hp": 7,
        "attack": Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1)
      },
      "Goblin": {
        "hp": 5,
        "attack": Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1)
      },
      "Snake": {
        "hp": 4,
        "attack": Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 2)
      },
      "Skeleton": {
        "hp": 6,
        "attack": Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1)
      }
    };
    var enemieHP = monsters[monster][stat];
    console.log("HP:");
    return [enemieHP];
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>rpg</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <div class="container-1">
    <button id="travel" class="btn-danger" onclick="travel()">Travel</button>
    <button id="attack" class="btn-danger" onclick="attack()">Attack</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how does the attack function look like?

Comment: Put only the `var happened;` outside the `travel` function's scope. Keep the `happened = pickEvent();` inside of `travel()` so that it's still executed every time the function is called from the button click. (Same for the other variables like `enemy` and `enemyHP`)

Comment: @eltonkamami i have'nt created it yet but it will minus a number between 1 and 4 from HP every time you run it, untill the HP is below 0. Later i'll try to add the character's hp so we can get hits and die too but for now it will just minus numbers from HP till it's below 0.

Comment: @Bergi thank you, gonna try it.

Comment: @Bergi thanks again, it worked i can get the same HP value in attack function now

Answer (score 0):

I whipped this up pretty quickly so please don't copy and paste, instead look through and try to understand why things are being done. If you need any help, I would be happy to collaborate. Please pm me.

```
//pull enemies out of function, makes it easy to add new enemies
    const ENEMIE_TYPES = [
        {
            name: 'Dire Wolf',
            'hp': 7,
            'attack': Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1),
        },
        { name: 'Goblin', 'hp': 5, 'attack': Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1) },
        { name: 'Snake', 'hp': 4, 'attack': Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 2) },
        { name: 'Skeleton', 'hp': 6, 'attack': Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1) },
    ];


// I would make these objects and defined a clear path inside the object so that you can add objects instead of having to change the impelmentation of the travel() function. however I don't want to confuse you too much; please look up polymorphism.
const EVENTS = ["Nothing happend...", "You are under attack:", "Some one should have dropped this:", "You see a structure here: "];


// instantiates a new enemy instance from enemy types
class Enemy {
    constructor(enemyType) {
        Object.assign(this,enemyType)
    }
    takeDamage(amount) {
        this.hp -= amount
    }
    attack(player) {
        player.hp -= this.attack
    }
}

// instantiates a new instance of the player in case you want to make the game multiplayer
class Player {
    constructor(hp, baseDamage) {
        this.hp = hp
        this.baseDamage = baseDamage
    }
    attack(enemy) {
        enemy.hp -= this.baseDamage
    }
}


//no need to have 2 functions based on what is being picked
function pick(Arr) {
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * Arr.length);
    return Arr[rand];
}

function travel() {
    var happened = pick(EVENTS)
    console.log(happened);
    if (happened === 'You are under attack:') {
        document.getElementById('travel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('attack').style.display = 'inline';
        return new Enemy(pick(ENEMIE_TYPES))
    }
}

function attack(player, monster) {
    player.attack(monster)
    monster.attack(player)
    console.log(`Player HP: ${player.hp}`)
    console.log(`${monster.name} HP: ${monster.hp}`)
}

// EXAMPLE:

const player1 = new Player(50, 10)
const monster = travel()
attack(player,monster) // attach this to the event listener for the attack button but this is a simple example
```